# Using pip in a conda envirnment, does that install the package within that conda environment only?

Tags: python, pip, conda

I have activated my environment using

```
conda activate deep_learning
```

After I get the bracket with the environment name, I proceed with an installation using

```
pip install numpy
```

Is the numpy now only installed within that conda environment? Or is also installed on the system level.

This case is for a windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Usually yes](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1429), but it isn't necessarily a good idea - the conda package manager won't know about your pip installs, and you might get some quirky behaviour: https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/

Common packages such as numpy and tensorflow can be installed using conda instead of pip.

If you just want to isolate a python environment and continue to manage packages with pip, you would be better off using venv/virtualenv.

Comment: `..using pip only after all other requirements have been installed via conda is the safest practice..` Fantastic, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After creating your new environment, you need to make sure you also installed pip to the environment by running `conda install pip`.

Then, you need to go to the address you created your new env, and `pip install newPackage`. This way, you can make sure that you installed the new package only on the new env, not system level.

Comment: Thanks for that, is there a documentation for this ? :=

Comment: I am not aware of a good one. But, you might get some idea here: https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/

Comment: Specially this part: 'Use conda environments for isolation':
- create a conda environment to isolate any changes pip makes
- environments take up little space thanks to hard links
- care should be taken to avoid running pip in the “root” environment